# Templates with pointers, creating 2d array

Tags: c++

I got a little problem with templates and pointer. I'm trying to create a 2d array for some different matrices with different types. I have to do it with templates and references where it makes sense.
My main function looks like this, I'm not allowed to change it:

```
int main(){
    int row, column;
    cin >> row;
    cin >> column;

    int** M1;
    double** M2;

    reserve(M1, row, column);
    reserve(M2, row, column);

    return 0;
}
```

So my reserve function would look something like this:

```
template <typename S>
void reserve(S &x, int row, int column){

  x = new S*[row];
  for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
      x[i] = new S[column];
  }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not getting the solution for this function. I tried it every way I could think about but nothing works. 
I think the problem is that I'm not working correct with the type** pointer in combination with the type-parameter. In the version I posted above, im getting errors like:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int****’ to ‘int**’ in assignment x = new S*[row];
```

Would love if someone could help me fixing this function.

Comment: Consider `template <typename S> void reserve(S **&x, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the signature of `reserve` to this should fix the compile error

```
template <typename S>
void reserve(S **&x, int row, int column)
```

Alternatively, you can implement `reserve` so that it returns the newly allocated array

```
template <typename S>
S** reserve(int row, int column)
{
    S** x = new S*[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        x[i] = new S[column];
    }

    return x;
}
```

Remember to delete the array using `delete []` when you are done using it:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this might help you; try to encapsulate the whole concept into a class object like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> Row; 

private:
    std::vector<Row> Mat;

    unsigned numberRows;
    unsigned numberColumns;

public:
    Matrix();
    explicit Matrix( std::vector<Row>& vRows );
    Matrix( unsigned numRows, unsigned numColumns );
    Matrix( unsigned numRows, unsigned numColumns, T** data );

    ~Matrix();

private:
    void reserve( unsigned int numRows, unsigned int numColumns );
};
```

Where this reserve() method is part of the class object where only this class has access to it. This would act as a helper function for your class in implementing its multiple constructors. If you want to use dynamic memory for the elements this can be expanded to this:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
   typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> Row;

private:
    std::vector<Row> Mat;

    // All Else Would Be The Same; Only The Internal Methods Would Slightly
    // Vary Due To The Use Of Smart Pointer And Dynamic Memory.
};
```

Then in your main this will simplify code.

```
int main() {

    // Using Default Constructor
    Matrix<float> fMat1;   

    // Using std::vector<Row> To Construct A Matrix
    Matrix<int>::Row row1;
    Matrix<int>::Row row2;
    Matrix<int>::Row row3;
    std::vector<Matrix<int>::Row> vRows
    Matrix<int>   iMat2( vRows );

    // A Construct That Knows The Size Of The Matrix; 
    // But Doesn't Have The Data
    Matrix<double> dMat3( 4, 4 ); // This Will Create A Size Of 4x4 Of
                                  // Doubles And Initialize Everything To 0 

    // Same As Above, But Passing In Raw Data By Double Pointer.
    float** pData = nullptr; 
    // Populate Pointer's Elements
    unsigned int row, col;
    // Store Size Of Row & Col Based On Pointer's Elements
    Matrix<float>( row, col, pData );

    return 0;
}
```

And that is about it! The constructors shouldn't be that hard to implement. And if you are only working with stack objects the first definition of the class will work, but if you need dynamic memory of all objects the second one will suite your needs and the use of smart pointers makes the cleaning up of dynamic memory much cleaner, easier and safer. Less prone to memory leaks.

This would also allow you to create a matrix when you have the data available upon creation of the matrix; or to make an empty matrix container available to set aside memory for later on when you are ready to populate it. You would just have to add the necessary methods to set, get data elements, and any appropriate operator overloads for performing basic operations. Maybe some public methods to do common work on data or to test if data is in matrix, etc.

Because this Matrix class is template the way it is; it is not subject to just basic raw day types. This can store class objects, structure, function pointers, events, threads, files and even more!